# Switching spaces in Lion: Ctrl+# (number key) not working

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-spaces, osx-lion

In Snow Leopard, I was able to switch between spaces using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> where <kbd>#</kbd> is a number key. However, after a fresh install of Lion it seems I have lost this feature. I can still switch using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>. Is it possible to re-enable the number key shortcut(s)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is present in system preferences.

It's under keyboard shortcuts:

[image]

Note that in the picture they're not enabled, but it's "Switch to Desktop #".

Comment: In (Mountain) Lion there is initially only `Switch to Desktop 1` and you have to **create** all the desktops in advance to be able to enable the shortcut. Note that the setting is persistent, even if it is not visible at any given time.